# if column value is duplicated then keep row based on multiple conditionals otherwise keep row

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, data.table

I would like to subset a data table to include records based on their dates and conditional values of two other columns (id and type variables). However, if only one record exists per id, regardless of the value of the other conditional column or date, then retain the record.

A sample of my data looks like this:

```
dt <- data.table(badge = c("1001", "1001", "1002", "1003", "1003", "1003", "1004", "1004"), location = c("training", "test", "training", "training", "test", "test", "training", "training"), date = as.POSIXct(c("2014-09-21", "2014-10-01", "2014-09-20", "2014-09-15", "2014-11-01", "2014-12-10", "2014-09-09", "2014-09-10")), score = as.numeric(c(3,5,-1,0,1,3,-2,1)))

> dt
   badge location       date score
1:  1001 training 2014-09-21     3
2:  1001     test 2014-10-01     5
3:  1002 training 2014-09-20    -1
4:  1003 training 2014-09-15     0
5:  1003     test 2014-11-01     1
6:  1003     test 2014-12-10     3
7:  1004 training 2014-09-09    -2
8:  1004 training 2014-09-10     1
```

For each badge, I am more interested in the test scores over the training score (row #2). However, if no test scores for a certain badge exist, then I want to retain the training score (row #3). If more than one test score per badge exists, I want to take the score on the earlier date (row #5). If more than one training score exist per badge but no test score, I want to take the score on the later date (row #8).

The result should look like this:

```
> dt
   badge location       date score
2:  1001     test 2014-10-01     5
3:  1002 training 2014-09-20    -1
5:  1003     test 2014-11-01     1
8:  1004 training 2014-09-10     1
```

I have tried variations of different dplyr strings and subsetting. `dt <- dt %>% group_by(badge) %>% filter(location=="test") %>% filter(date == min(date))` is the closest I've gotten as it gives me the earliest test scores by badge, but removes all training records regardless if there is a test score for that badge. I can see why this code doesn't work as I am asking it to be selective, but I don't know how to make it more nuanced to produce the result I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an alternative solution which orders only once to avoid repeated reordering while grouping:

```
library(data.table)
tmp <- dt[order(date), if (any(location == "test")) 
  first(.I[location == "test"]) else last(.I), keyby = badge]
dt[tmp$V1]
```

> ```
>    badge location       date score
> 1:  1001     test 2014-10-01     5
> 2:  1002 training 2014-09-20    -1
> 3:  1003     test 2014-11-01     1
> 4:  1004 training 2014-09-10     1
> ```

For better explanation, I have introduced `tmp` although this is not really required. `tmp` holds the indices of the selected records in `V1`:

> ```
>    badge V1
> 1:  1001  2
> 2:  1002  3
> 3:  1003  5
> 4:  1004  8
> ```

Comment: I chose this answer for its simplicity and brevity. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I think this is the logic you want:

```
library(data.table)
myfunc <- function(x) {
 if (!'test' %in% x$location) {
  out <- setorder(x, -date)
 } else {
  out <- setorder(x, location, date)
 }
 out[1, ]
}

dt[, myfunc(.SD), by = 'badge']
#   badge location       date score
#1:  1003     test 2014-11-01     1
#2:  1001     test 2014-10-01     5
#3:  1002 training 2014-09-20    -1
#4:  1004 training 2014-09-10     1
```

I made a user defined function based on your logic (to order the data.table and return the first row) and used on each badge group.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution using `dplyr` is with use of `filter`, `join` and the `union_all`.

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)


    dt <- data.table(badge = c("1001", "1001", "1002", "1003", "1003", "1003", "1004", "1004"),
location = c("training", "test", "training", "training", "test", "test", "training", "training"), 
date = as.POSIXct(c("2014-09-21", "2014-10-01", "2014-09-20", "2014-09-15", "2014-11-01", "2014-12-10", "2014-09-09", "2014-09-10")), 
score = as.numeric(c(3,5,-1,0,1,3,-2,1)))


        # Rows with badge having both "test" and "training". Data with "test" is preferred
        df_test <- dt %>% filter(location == "test") %>%
        inner_join(filter(dt, location == "training"), by="badge") %>%
        select(badge, location = location.x, date = date.x, score = score.x)

        # Data for badge with only "training" records
        df_training <- dt %>% filter(location == "training") %>%
          anti_join(filter(dt, location == "test"), by="badge")

        # combine both
        union_all(df_test, df_training)

        # The result will look like:
        > union_all(df_test, df_training)
          badge location       date score
        1  1001     test 2014-10-01     5
        2  1003     test 2014-11-01     1
        3  1003     test 2014-12-10     3
        4  1002 training 2014-09-20    -1
        5  1004 training 2014-09-09    -2
        6  1004 training 2014-09-10     1
```

Not sure if OP wants to keep `duplicate` records in `same location`. If duplicate records are not needed then those can be filtered out using `distinct`.

Comment: Please, review your answer as it does not return the expected result. In particular, the OP has explained that he wants duplicate entries to be treated differently for test and training cases. So, it is more than simply using `distinct()`.